# Is there a Maintenance Plan that checks my database for corruption?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, corruption, maintenance-plans, maintenance

Is there any way to make a maintenance plan check all my databases on a single instance?
Is the maintenance plan `Check Database Integrity Task` enough ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. The integrity check in the maintenance plan is enough since it will run a `dbcc checkdb`.
From MSDN:

[integrity check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139858.aspx)

> The Check Database Integrity task encapsulates the DBCC CHECKDB statement.

Running this task will be resource intensive. You don't want to do this in prod. servers if you don't have a maintenance window.

The common way is the following:

**1. Backup your databases**

**2. Restore your db's on a test environment**

**3. Run a `dbcc checkdb` on your databases.**

This way you check your DB integrity and verify your backup.

Answer (score 3):

[@RayofCommand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125861/22336), has already given an appropriate answer, but will like to add more which is very helpful and easy to track for any corrupt databases using [SQL Server Integrity Check](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html) from [ola hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/).

> Is the maintenance plan Check Database Integrity Task enough ?

1. Well, for this should check some more details on this as explained by Kendra on [DBCC CheckDB FAQ: Check for Corruption in SQL Server](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/dbcc-checkdb-faq/)
2. You should also set alerts fro any corruption as a proactive alerts as explained [here](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/configure-sql-server-alerts/)
3. Last but not least, please refer to this great blog post from @Aaron [Minimizing the impact of DBCC CHECKDB : DOs and DON'Ts](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/io-subsystem/minimize-impact-of-checkdb)..